# Changing primary in $theme-colors made btn-primary's text color to black instead of default white

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

```
$theme-colors:(
    "primary": #F58220
);

@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

But `<button class="btn btn-primary w-100 text-center">Continue</button>` made the text color black instead of the default white. How did that get changed automatically ?

EDIT : When I edit "primary" then all others like danger etc get removed.
All I want to do is to edit "primary" keeping the remaining as it is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `$theme-colors:()` is not adding to it, but overwriting it.
I solved by just overwriting `$primary`.

```
$primary: #F58220;

@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```